# What's the best way to write the phrase "apply as a spot treatment"?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico

I'm trying to translate an English prescription label into Spanish. The full instructions are:

> Apply to affected area on face twice daily as **spot treatment** or once daily to entire face.

I was wondering if there was an equivalent phrase to "spot treatment" that would make sense to a Spanish speaker.

What I have tentatively is:

> Aplicar sobre el área afectada en la cara dos veces al día según sea necesario como **tratamiento spot** o una vez al día en toda la cara".

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use *puntual* or *localizada* as alternatives

> Aplicar sobre el área afectada **de manera puntual** dos veces al día o sobre toda la cara una vez al día.

or

> Aplicar **de manera localizada** sobre el área afectada dos veces al día o sobre toda la cara una vez al día.

You can also replace the bold part for *puntualmente* or *localmente*

Comment: Bien hecho.  Entre las diferentes opciones que diste, la que más me gusta es "de manera localizada."